# Does C# have the same semantics for return values and parameters as Java?

Tags: java, c#

I am trying to learn C# via Unity, and I was wondering does C# have the same semantics as Java when it comes to pass-by-reference or pass-by-value for parameters and return values?

I see in the C# language that you can use `ref` to indicate something is pass by reference, does that mean it is pass by value by default?

Java being pass by reference by default unless it is a primitive type (i.e. something that does not extend from `Object`)

That includes arrays in Java.  But I am not sure about C#.

Comment: Related: [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java is always pass-by-value, for both primitive types and non-primitive types.

e.g.,

```
void JavaMethod(int i, Foo f)
{
    i = 9; //not changed from caller's point of view
    f = new Foo(); //not changed from caller's point of view
}
```

C# is pass-by-value unless the 'ref' keyword is used:

```
void CSharpMethod(int i, Foo f, ref int j, ref Bar b)
{
    i = 9; //not changed from caller's point of view
    f = new Foo(); //not changed from caller's point of view

    j = 9; //changed from caller's point of view
    b = new Bar(); //changed from caller's point of view
}
```

In both languages, you can modify the internal state of an non-primitive object when it is passed by value:

```
void JavaOrCSharpMethod(Foo f)
{
    f.field = 9; //internal state is changed from caller's point of view
}
```

Keep in mind the difference between assigning a new instance to a parameter and modifying the internal state of the object. Not understanding this is the source of a lot of confusion about this subject.

Also, there is no real substance in whether a primitive type or non-primitive type is used, other than the fact that primitive types do not have members which change their state, so it's always done via assignment. Any non-primitive type where state can only be changed via assignment would seem the same.

I would include some C++ examples also, but this would drastically complicate the discussion since C++ has many ways of implementing pass-by-reference.